# Not able to access iterator() from RestTraverser, it gives exception java.lang.IllegalAccessError

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, graph-traversal

I am implementing traversal framework using neo4j java-rest-binding project.
Code is as follows:

```
RestAPI db = new RestAPIFacade("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
RestNode n21 = db.getNodeById(21);
Map<String,Object> traversalDesc = new HashMap<String, Object>();
traversalDesc.put("order", "breadth_first");
traversalDesc.put("uniqueness", "node_global");
traversalDesc.put("uniqueness", "relationship_global");
traversalDesc.put("returnType", "fullpath");
traversalDesc.put("max_depth", 2);
RestTraverser traverser = db.traverse(n21, traversalDesc);
Iterable<Node> nodes = traverser.nodes();
System.out.println("All Nodes:");      // First Task
for(Node n:nodes){
System.out.println(n.getId());
}
Iterable<Relationship> rels = traverser.relationships();
System.out.println("All Relations:");  // Second Task
for(Relationship r:rels){
System.out.println(r.getId());
}
Iterator<Path> paths = traverser.iterator();  // Third Task
while(paths.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(paths.next());
}
```

I need to do 3 tasks as commented in the code:

1. Print all the node IDs related to node no. 21
2. Print all the relation IDs related to node no. 21
3. Traverse all the paths related to node no. 21

Tasks 1 & 2 are working fine.
But when I try to do `traverser.iterator()` in 3rd task it throws an Exception saying:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.neo4j.helpers.collection.WrappingResourceIterator from class org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.traversal.RestTraverser
```

Can anyone please check why this is happening or if I am doing wrong then what is the right method to do it.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace?

Comment: What neo4j version do you have in your client project? And which version of java-rest-binding? They should match.

Comment: I got the same `java.lang.IllegalAccessError: org/neo4j/helpers/collection/WrappingResourceIterator` using 2.0.1 neo4j and java-rest-binding (neo4j-rest-graphdb.jar). It looks like `org.neo4j.helpers.collection.WrappingResourceIterator` has been made `package` visbile in [neo4j-kernel](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blame/master/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/helpers/collection/WrappingResourceIterator.java)

Comment: But java-rest-binding is using its own `public`[copy](https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding/blob/2.0-labels-and-indexes/src/main/java/org/neo4j/helpers/collection/WrappingResourceIterator.java) ?!@ so if you're having both neo4j-kernel.jar and neo4j-rest-graphdb.jar in the same classpath the former is being picked up first and cause the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe using the Neo4j Traversal Framework via the REST DB binding is properly supported, nor is it advisable.  If you traverse via REST, each node and each relationship will be retrieved over the network as the traversal proceeds, incurring a tremendous overhead for the traversal.

**Edit**: The above is not true, the REST traverser is smarter than I thought.

In general, it will be faster to use Cypher, and access the Neo4j Server using JDBC. Read more about JDBC here: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc

If you really want to use the Traversal Framework, you should use Server Extensions, which allow you to design a traversal to run on the server itself, and then only move the result of the traversal over the network. Read more about server extensions here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html

Comment: Actually the rest-traverser collects the information on the client and sends a traversal description to the server to be executed.